# Can't use variable as field name updateDoc (firebase)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

How can i write a variable there? This is React.
`${}` and ""+"" are not working

> Pls i neeed help

```
const id = 'currentChat[0].
id';
const fn = async () => {
    await updateDoc(contactsRef, {
        `${id}.chatHistory`: arrayUnion(message),
    });};
fn();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an expression, you need to put it inside `[]`. These are called computed property names.

You need to use

```
[`${id}.chatHistory/`]
```

Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names).

Comment: Thanks! But there should be ```[`${id}.chatHistory`]```

Comment: Yup, minor typo. Let me know if it works